# How do I use arrays in the draw() method?

Tags: java, arrays, animation, processing, draw

I'm making a program in [Processing](http://processing.org/) (a language very similar to Java) which takes data I've sorted using python into text files and then added to the processing sketch and displays them in scrollable bubbles. I want the array index to increase by one each time I release the mouse button so all the songs (that's the data I sorted) can be viewed by clicking and releasing. The problem is Processing won't let me use the arrays I've loaded the files into in the `draw()` method even though both my `setup()` and `draw()` methods are public. The error it gives me is `NullPointerException` on line 82:

```
text(songsort[a1],close,15,99,99);
```

It also says that my files are missing and unreadable when it can read them in the `setup()`. I'd really appreciate your help.

Here is my code:

```
import de.looksgood.ani.*;
import de.looksgood.ani.easing.*;
PFont f;
int x=50;
int i=50;
int y=50;
int far=999;
int mid=666;
int close=333;
int end=1333;
int y1=113;
int far2=999;
int mid2=666;
int close2=333;
int end2=1333;
int y2=339;
int far3=999;
int mid3=666;
int close3=333;
int end3=1333;
int y3=567;
int a1=1;
int a2=2;
int a3=3;
int a4=4;
int b1=1;
int b2=2;
int b3=3;
int b4=4;
int c1=1;
int c2=2;
int c3=3;
int c4=4;

public void setup(){
  size(1333,680);
  smooth();
  f = createFont("Georgia", 32);
  textFont(f);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  String[] songsort= loadStrings("songsort.txt");
  String[] artistsort= loadStrings("yearsort.txt");
  String[] yearsort= loadStrings("artistsort.txt");
  println("There are "+songsort.length+artistsort.length+yearsort.length+" lines");

  Ani.init(this);
  Ani.setDefaultEasing(Ani.QUART_IN_OUT);
}

public void draw(){
    background(169);


    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    rect(x,1,100,height/3);

    textFont(f);
    textSize(32);
    fill(50);
    text("sorted by year",x,15,100,height/3);

    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(far,y1,99,99);
    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(mid,y1,99,99);
    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(close,y1,99,99);
    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(end,y1,99,99);

    textFont(f);
    textSize(16);
    fill(255);
    text(songsort[1],close,15,99,99); ///////////// Error here! /////////////


   if((mouseX<1333) && (mouseX>0) && (mouseY>0) && (mouseY<226) && (mousePressed==true)){
     x=x-5;
     end=end-5;
     far=far-5;
     mid=mid-5;
     close=close-5;
   }

    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    rect(i,226.66,100,height/3);

    textFont(f);
    textSize(32);
    fill(50);
    text("sorted by song name",i,226.66,100,height/3);

    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(far2,y2,99,99);
    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(mid2,y2,99,99);
    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(close2,y2,99,99);
    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(end2,y2,99,99);

    if((mouseX<1333) && (mouseX>0) && (mouseY>226.66) && (mouseY<453.34) && (mousePressed==true)){
       i=i-5;
     end2=end2-5;
     far2=far2-5;
     mid2=mid2-5;
     close2=close2-5;
     }

    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    rect(y,453.34,100,height/3);

    textFont(f);
    textSize(32);
    fill(50);
    text("sorted by artist",y,453.34,100,height/3);

    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    ellipse(far3,y3,99,99);
    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    ellipse(mid3,y3,99,99);
    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    ellipse(close3,y3,99,99);
    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    ellipse(end3,y3,99,99);

   if((mouseX<1333) && (mouseX>0) && (mouseY>453.34) && (mouseY<680) && (mousePressed==true)){
     y=y-5;
     end3=end3-5;
     far3=far3-5;
     mid3=mid3-5;
     close3=close3-5;
   } 
}

void mouseReleased(){
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "close", 133);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "mid", 466);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "far", 799);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "end", 1133);   
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "close2", 133);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "mid2", 466);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "far2", 799);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "end2", 1133);   
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "close3", 133);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "mid3", 466);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "far3", 799);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "end3", 1133);   
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: On what line is the NullPointerException?

Comment: The question and code example is so out of context that it is impossible to even begin to understand the root of the problem let alone try and provide any kind of suggestions for fixing it...try providing a runnable example of the problem...

Comment: @RyanCarlson line 82:    text(songsort[a1],close,15,99,99);

Answer (score 2):

Your arrays are declared as local variables in function setup(), therefore they are not visible outside of this function. To make them visible in other functions of your class, you should declare them as fields of this class.

```
public class YourClass {

    private String[] songsort;

    private String[] artistsort;

    private String[] yearsort;

    public void setup() {
        ...
        songsort = loadStrings("songsort.txt");
        artistsort = loadStrings("yearsort.txt");
        yearsort = loadStrings("artistsort.txt");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I get: The method init(PApplet) in the type Ani is not applicable for the arguments (VIsualization.visualization)   FYI visualization is what i named my class.

Comment: Method init(PApplet) in the type Ani expects that its arguments would be objects of class PApplet or its subclass and it looks like your Visualization.visualization class isn't.

Are you using any IDE for development? If not, try to use Eclipse or IDEA IntelliJ Community. Both are free and they underline compiler errors by default while you're coding, therefore you don't need to wait for compilation in order to verify your code.

Comment: @TomaszBekas The question's code is in [Processing](http://processing.org/), not Java. In many questions the subtle difference is irrelevant, but in this one the language _does_ matter.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used the Processing Develop Environment. Anyhow, I just used what Ryan Carlson said because it worked with more ease but, I really appreciate the help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very stripped-down version of your code:

```
                                                    //0
public void setup() {                               //1
  String[] songsort = loadStrings("songsort.txt");  //2
}                                                   //3
                                                    //4
public void draw() {                                //5
    text(songsort[1],close,15,99,99);               //6
}                                                   //7
```

On line 2, you declare the variable `songsort` by using `String[] songsort`. Because this is in the method `setup`, the variable `songsort` is a "local variable", and is only accessible in that method. To fix this, *declare* the variable on line 0, but still *initialize* it in the `setup` method, like this:

```
String[] songsort;                                  //0
public void setup() {                               //1
  songsort = loadStrings("songsort.txt");           //2
}                                                   //3
                                                    //4
public void draw() {                                //5
    text(songsort[1],close,15,99,99);               //6
}                                                   //7
```

Doing this to all your `String[]`s and applying it to the code you have should look like this:

```
import de.looksgood.ani.*;
import de.looksgood.ani.easing.*;

String[] songsort;
String[] artistsort;
String[] yearsort;

PFont f;
int x=50;
int i=50;
int y=50;
int far=999;
int mid=666;
int close=333;
int end=1333;
int y1=113;
int far2=999;
int mid2=666;
int close2=333;
int end2=1333;
int y2=339;
int far3=999;
int mid3=666;
int close3=333;
int end3=1333;
int y3=567;
int a1=1;
int a2=2;
int a3=3;
int a4=4;
int b1=1;
int b2=2;
int b3=3;
int b4=4;
int c1=1;
int c2=2;
int c3=3;
int c4=4;

public void setup() {
  size(1333,680);
  smooth();
  f = createFont("Georgia", 32);
  textFont(f);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);

  songsort= loadStrings("songsort.txt");
  artistsort= loadStrings("yearsort.txt");
  yearsort= loadStrings("artistsort.txt");

  println("There are "+songsort.length+artistsort.length+yearsort.length+" lines");

  Ani.init(this);
  Ani.setDefaultEasing(Ani.QUART_IN_OUT);
}

public void draw() {
    background(169);


    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    rect(x,1,100,height/3);

    textFont(f);
    textSize(32);
    fill(50);
    text("sorted by year",x,15,100,height/3);

    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(far,y1,99,99);
    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(mid,y1,99,99);
    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(close,y1,99,99);
    fill(123,43,23);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(end,y1,99,99);

    textFont(f);
    textSize(16);
    fill(255);
    text(songsort[1],close,15,99,99);


   if((mouseX<1333) && (mouseX>0) && (mouseY>0) && (mouseY<226) && (mousePressed==true)) {
     x=x-5;
     end=end-5;
     far=far-5;
     mid=mid-5;
     close=close-5;
   }

    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    rect(i,226.66,100,height/3);

    textFont(f);
    textSize(32);
    fill(50);
    text("sorted by song name",i,226.66,100,height/3);

    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(far2,y2,99,99);
    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(mid2,y2,99,99);
    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(close2,y2,99,99);
    fill(43,123,23);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(end2,y2,99,99);

    if((mouseX<1333) && (mouseX>0) && (mouseY>226.66) && (mouseY<453.34) && (mousePressed==true)) {
       i=i-5;
     end2=end2-5;
     far2=far2-5;
     mid2=mid2-5;
     close2=close2-5;
     }

    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    rect(y,453.34,100,height/3);

    textFont(f);
    textSize(32);
    fill(50);
    text("sorted by artist",y,453.34,100,height/3);

    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    ellipse(far3,y3,99,99);
    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    ellipse(mid3,y3,99,99);
    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    ellipse(close3,y3,99,99);
    fill(240,179,93);
    stroke(147);
    ellipse(end3,y3,99,99);

   if((mouseX<1333) && (mouseX>0) && (mouseY>453.34) && (mouseY<680) && (mousePressed==true)) {
     y=y-5;
     end3=end3-5;
     far3=far3-5;
     mid3=mid3-5;
     close3=close3-5;
   } 
}

void mouseReleased() {
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "close", 133);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "mid", 466);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "far", 799);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "end", 1133);   
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "close2", 133);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "mid2", 466);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "far2", 799);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "end2", 1133);   
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "close3", 133);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "mid3", 466);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "far3", 799);
  Ani.to(this, 1.0, "end3", 1133);   
}
```

The variables `songsort`, `artistsort`, and `yearsort` should then be "fields", which are accessible throughout the entire tab, and in this case, sketch.